# Why can't I login to my wordpress at home?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I don't have the same issue in the office but when I try to login at home, it keeps on saying "too many redirects". I'm not very good at this FTP thing so can anyone help me what to do? I've tried clearing the caches and cookies. Nothing's helped so far. I tried the FTP and it says, "Critical Error: Cannot connect to server."

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can cause a looping issue in wordpress.

First thing I would do is to go into the dashboard, assuming you can, and simply resave the permalinks.

If that doesn't work, in *general > settings* if you have `https://example.com`, change it to `https://www.example.com` or vice versa.  Make sure that you don’t leave a trailing slash at the end of your URL like `https://www.example.com/`

If you can't get into the dashboard, in your `wp-config.php` file add the lines

`define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');`

also try it with the `www` to manually define the site home and URL.

If none of those work, try deactivating all plugins.

As a last resort, (or maybe a first step), contact tech support at your host.